# Android Studio 2.0 Update Cant Run App/Theme Error

Tags: android-activity, launch

I just updated android studio to 2.0 and I can't run my themes anymore. I am getting the following error:

> 19:59:20 Executing tasks: [:theme:assembleDebug] 19:59:25 Gradle build
>   finished in 5s 506ms 19:59:28 Can't bind to local 8637 for debugger
>   19:59:32 Session 'theme': Error Launching activity
>
> Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found Error
>   while Launching activity

What is wrong?

```
<uses-feature android:required="true" android:name="org.cyanogenmod.theme" />

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<meta-data android:name="org.cyanogenmod.theme.name" android:value="@string/theme_name"/>
<meta-data android:name="org.cyanogenmod.theme.author" android:value="@string/theme_author" />
<meta-data android:name="org.cyanogenmod.theme.email" android:value="@string/theme_email" />

<application android:hasCode="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/theme_name"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable `Instant Run` to resolve this problem.

> File(Ctrl + Alt + S) > Setting > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run > Uncheck all checkbox option to disable.

Try:
Step 1:

> File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...

Step 2:

This is all code in `AndroidManifest.xml? You should have at least one activity that looks something like this::

```
<activity
        android:name="com.your.package.name.YourActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This should be between:

`<application> </application>`